# Html required attribute not working with button function

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onclick, required

My goal is to display the form input data on a pop up window after the submit button has been pressed. Problem is that some fields can't be empty, so I have used required attribute which doesn't seem to work when button has onClick function. 
If i use onSubmit option then the pop up window does not appear.

HTML:

```
   <form id="form1" name="form1" action="" method="post">
<p><b> First Name:</b> <input type="text" name="firstname" size="30" maxlength="25" required />
</p>
<p><b>Last Name:</b> <input type="text" name="lastname" size="30" maxlength="25" required />
</p>
<p><b>Gender: </b> 
    <select name="gender" required />
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
</select>
</p>
<p><b>Age:</b>
        <input type="text" name="age" size="30" min="18" max="100" required />
    </p>
<p><b>Email:</b>
    <input type="email" name="email" size="30" maxlength="50" required />
</p>
<p><b>Website:</b>
        <input type="url" name="website" size="30" maxlength="50" required />
    </p>

<p><b>Comment:</b>
<br/>
    <textarea name="comment" cols="20" rows="4" size="30" maxlength="255">Enter your text</textarea>
</p>
<button type="submit" value="submit" onsubmit="display();" id="save">Submit</button>

</form>
<script src="JS/contactForm.js"></script>
```

Javascript:

```
function display() {

  DispWin = window.open('','NewWin', 'toolbar=no,status=no,width=400,height=500')
  message = "<b>Submitted inputs: </b><br/> <br/>" + "<b>First Name: </b>" + document.form1.firstname.value + "<br/>";
  message += "<b>Last Name: </b>" + document.form1.lastname.value + "<br/>";
  message += "<b>Gender: </b>" + document.form1.gender.value + "<br/>";
  message += "<b>Last Name: </b>" + document.form1.age.value + "<br/>";
  message += "<b>Last Name: </b>" + document.form1.email.value + "<br/>";
  message += "<b>Last Name: </b>" + document.form1.website.value + "<br/>";
  message += "<b>Comment: </b>" + document.form1.comment.value + "<br/>";
  DispWin.document.write(message);
}
```

I have tried to search for similar problems but couldn't find anything. Hopefully someone can guide me how to fix this problem or teach me how to google better.

Cheers!

Comment: `onsubmit` is a form event...not a button event

Comment: Thanks. That helped me to discover that I have to put onSubmit to form tag instead.

Comment: Yes.....exactly

Comment: Try making the `required` attribute `required="required"`.

Answer (score 1):

In your display function add a check if form is valid or not before executing function code.

for example if you are using jquery lib:

```
function display() {
  if (($('form1')[0].checkValidity()) {
   // your rest of code
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Made the button to

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="save" />
```

and put the onsubmit to the form tag instead and now it works.

```
<form id="form1" onsubmit="display()" name="form1" action="" method="post">
```

Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Giving Informative way to answer your question

Just Don't make any changes to button,
just remove **onsubmit="display()"** on the button and add to your form tag.
and it will work.You can also use javascript to submit your form while using onclick and placing more validating conditions(**if-else**) on javascript side as compare to Required Attribute for those controls that can't be validated using required.

Answer (score -1):

Try This :

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" action="" method="post">
    <p><b> First Name:</b> <input type="text" name="firstname" size="30" maxlength="25" required />
    </p>
    <p><b>Last Name:</b> <input type="text" name="lastname" size="30" maxlength="25" required />
    </p>
    <p><b>Gender: </b> 
        <select name="gender" required />
            <option value="Female">Female</option>
            <option value="Male">Male</option>
    </select>
    </p>
    <p><b>Age:</b>
            <input type="text" name="age" size="30" min="18" max="100" required />
        </p>
    <p><b>Email:</b>
        <input type="email" name="email" size="30" maxlength="50" required />
    </p>
    <p><b>Website:</b>
            <input type="url" name="website" size="30" maxlength="50" required />
        </p>

    <p><b>Comment:</b>
    <br/>
        <textarea name="comment" cols="20" rows="4" size="30" maxlength="255">Enter your text</textarea>
    </p>
    <button type="submit" value="submit" id="save">Submit</button>

    </form>

    <script>
        document.getElementById("form1").addEventListener("submit", function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            DispWin = window.open('','NewWin', 'toolbar=no,status=no,width=400,height=500')
            message = "<b>Submitted inputs: </b><br/> <br/>" + "<b>First Name: </b>" + document.form1.firstname.value + "<br/>";
            message += "<b>Last Name: </b>" + document.form1.lastname.value + "<br/>";
            message += "<b>Gender: </b>" + document.form1.gender.value + "<br/>";
            message += "<b>Last Name: </b>" + document.form1.age.value + "<br/>";
            message += "<b>Last Name: </b>" + document.form1.email.value + "<br/>";
            message += "<b>Last Name: </b>" + document.form1.website.value + "<br/>";
            message += "<b>Comment: </b>" + document.form1.comment.value + "<br/>";
            DispWin.document.write(message);
        });

    </script>
```